# PHP removing commas, stops, questionmarks... from string

Tags: php

Let's say I have string like this:

```
$string = "I have big, nice, green house!?"
```

What I want to do is to remove characters like ', . ! ? : "" ''' from my string.

How to do this?
I tryed rtrim() function, but I was able to remove only one kind of characters but not all of them.

Comment: What you have tried for it?

Answer (score 4):

Use `str_replace()` with array of special character -

```
$string = "I have big, nice, green house!?";

echo $content = str_replace(['.', ',', '?', '!'], '', $string);
```

**Output**

> I have big nice green house

Or if you want to remove all of them then try with `regex` -

```
echo $content = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put as first param of `str_replace` function array of invalid chars.

```
echo str_replace(array(',', '.', '?', ...), '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$string = "I have big, nice, green house!?";
echo $tes=preg_replace('/[.,?!]/', '', $string);
```